# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 1^+} \log (x)^{\log(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 1^+} \log (x)^{\log(x)}$ ?
i know that its "1", but why?
How can i calculate this?

Thank you very very much =)

Comment: you can write this message in latex. use $ for the latex text.

Comment: "Let $\log x=u$."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substituting $t = \log x$ you obtain
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+} \log(x)^{\log(x)} = \lim_{t \to 0^+} t^t = \lim_{t \to 0^+} e^{t \log(t)} = e^{\lim_{t \to 0^+} t \log(t)}.
$$
To compute $\lim_{t \to 0^+} t \log(t)$ use, for example, de l'Hospital rule.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compute this limit you simply make the substitution $t=\log x$, which is possible because $\log$ is a continuous invertible function. Then the limit is just
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t^t
$$
that's quite easy to compute. Write it
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t^t=\lim_{t\to0^+}e^{t\log t}
$$
and compute
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\log t=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log t}{1/t}
$$
As you see, this has the form "$0/0$", so it's not computable just by substitution.

Comment: @Xorkox You have to work a bit harder. I'll add a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \log x = u $.

Then $ u \to 0^+ $ and you have the limit:

$\lim_{u\to 0^+} u^{u}$

which can be calculated if we consider the fact that

$ u^u = e^{ulnu}$ for $u>0$

and then apply L'Hopital's rule to $\lim_{u\to 0^+}ulnu$ :)